# How to find parent node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of data that represent hierarchy as follows.

```
MATCH (dv:DATview {SUPid: 'VIE_ClassMeronomy_01' })<-[:TOV_CLASSIFIES]-(mv:METtypeOfView),     
(mv)<-[:TOO_CONSTRAINS_TOV]-(mo:METtypeOfObject)-[:TOO_CLASSIFIES(a:DATobject),     
(mv)<-[:TOL_CONSTRAINS_TOV]-(ml:METtypeOfLink)-[:TOL_CLASSIFIES]->(d:DATlink)  
return a,d
```

[image]

I tried execute following query to get parent node "Test Class A", but it returns every nodes. Assumption was if no incoming LNK to a node, that node is a parent node.

```
MATCH (dv:DATview {SUPid: 'VIE_ClassMeronomy_01' })<-[:TOV_CLASSIFIES]-(mv:METtypeOfView),     
(mv)<-[:TOO_CONSTRAINS_TOV]-(mo:METtypeOfObject)-[:TOO_CLASSIFIES(a:DATobject),     
(mv)<-[:TOL_CONSTRAINS_TOV]-(ml:METtypeOfLink)-[:TOL_CLASSIFIES]->(d:DATlink)  
WHERE NOT (d)-[:LNK]->(a) 
return a,d
```

How can I find only the parent node?

Comment: So from your node `(d:DATlink)` you want to search the `root` one ?

Comment: Your image shows `LINK` relationships, but your queries (which are syntactically incorrect) do not mention them at all. What exactly is your data model, and what exactly are your trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

In your query, you go through all possible combinations of pairs of objects of the `DATobject` and `DATlink` type, and of course for each node `DATobject` is a node of the `DATlink`, with which it is not in relation.

And you need to find a node in which there is no link at all:

```
MATCH (d:DATobject) WHERE NOT (:DATlink)-[:LNK]->(d) 
RETURN d
```

Comment: Well actually I can't use (:DATlink) there because they are classified. I have edited my question again. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, assuming you just want the direct parent, and you have the id of the child (lets use `VIE_ClassMeronomy_01`) Than you can just match

`MATCH (parent)-->(child:DATview {SUPid: 'VIE_ClassMeronomy_01' }) return *`

but since your data has the intermediary nodes, it would be

`MATCH (parent)-->()-->(child:DATview {SUPid: 'VIE_ClassMeronomy_01' }) return *`

And if you actually want the root node, you can just ask for nodes with no incoming links

`MATCH (root) WHERE NOT ()-->(root) RETURN root`

And of course, use labels/defining properties in the MATCH as needed and known.

On a side note http://console.neo4j.org/ is a great way to share example data so that people can get a better idea of your setup and constraints. (Far more useful than pics)

EDIT:

You can also do a hybrid, get root from ID node

`MATCH (root)-[*]->(target{id:"heyo"}) WHERE NOT ()-->(root) RETURN root`

or, depending on your data, this may be faster

`MATCH (root), (target{id:"heyo"}) WHERE NOT ()-->(root) MATCH (root)-[*]->(target) RETURN root`